# How to check/uncheck all check boxes using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I'm new in AngularJS and trying to achieve check/uncheck all check boxes by clicking "toggle" button, which is styled by bootstrap.

Markup:

```
<button id="toggle" class="btn btn-link btn-mini" ng-click="setActionTypesAllCheck()">Check all</button>

<div class="row-fluid" ng-repeat="at in actionsQuery.actionTypes">
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="at.checked">{{at.Description}}</label>
</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.setActionTypesAllCheck = function () {
    $.each($scope.actionsQuery.actionTypes, function (i, cb) {
        cb.checked = !cb.checked;
    });
};
```

At this moment the code in JavaScript checks and unchecks all check boxes, but it doesn't take into account if some of them was manually checked/unchecked, which means it doesn't work properly.

So, I need to check all check boxes by clicking "toggle" button and change its name to "Uncheck all" no matter if some of check boxes is checked or not and vice versa, that is to uncheck all check boxes and change its name to "Check all" no matter if some of check boxes is checked or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);


function MainCtrl() {

  var vm = this;
  vm.message = "Welcome";
  vm.actionsQuery =

    {
      actionTypes: [

        {
          checked: true,
          Description: "Jon"
        }, {
          checked: false,
          Description: "Bon"
        }, {
          checked: false,
          Description: "Tim"
        }

      ]
    };
  vm.selected = function() {


  }
  vm.checkoxesState = true;

  vm.UpdateCheckboxes = function() {


    angular.forEach(vm.actionsQuery.actionTypes, function(at) {

      at.checked = vm.checkoxesState;

    });
    vm.checkoxesState = !this.checkoxesState


  };




}





angular.module("app").controller("MainCtrl", MainCtrl);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="app">

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
  <div class="container">
    <h3>{{vm.message}}</h3>
<form>
    <button id="toggle" class="btn btn-link btn-mini" ng-click="vm.UpdateCheckboxes()">
      <span ng-show="vm.checkoxesState">   Check all </span>
      <span ng-hide="vm.checkoxesState">   Uncheck All </span>
    </button>


    <div class="row-fluid" ng-repeat="at in vm.actionsQuery.actionTypes">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="at.checked">{{at.Description}}</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I need to change to text on button as well in the following way: when all check boxes are checked to "Uncheck all" and vice versa.

Comment: @tesicg and which button should be shown when only one 'checkbox' is checked ?

Comment: There should be only one button, not two.

Comment: @tesicg ok but which one if one checkbox is selected ?

Comment: I have an additional question about this solution - why this code is doing post back when <form> tag exists on the page?

Comment: @tesicg I've added form tag to sample code and everything is fine please see more likely I've got something else can you please create plunkr otherwise is difficult to advice

Comment: It's ok. I'm gonna ask another question because it's difficult to create plunkr.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [this](http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/) directive for checkboxes. Its simple and it has examples that you need.