# How to check all and un-check all static checkboxes in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I'm having some static checkboxes and one checkbox use for "Check All" in HTML file. Then i want to check or un-check all of these checkbox when i click on the "Check All" checkbox. But i still not know where is approach of this stuff.

HTML code:

```
<div>
   <input type="checkbox" name="check_all" ng-model="formFruit.fruits.all" ng-true-value=":all:"/> Select All </br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="" ng-model="formFruit.fruits.apple" ng-true-value=":apple:"/> Apple </br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="" ng-model="formFruit.fruits.banana" ng-true-value=":banana:"/> Banana </br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, why you have different model names for each checkbox,you can reset it to false or clear those values as follows,

```
angular.forEach($scope.formFruit.fruits, function(furit) {        
    //sett it to false
});
```

or

```
$scope.formFruit.fruits = [];
```

Comment: I have to make each of checkboxes with the different of model name because of i want to identity each of them and their value to check when i load edit form. So is that a bad way to do???

Comment: yeah, you should have single property with true/false only. check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26017286/how-to-check-uncheck-all-check-boxes-using-angularjs

Comment: I want to use specify value because when checkbox is checked and submit, server with concat all checked checkboxes to a string. For example if apple and banana are checked, server with have a string ````:apple::banaa:````. So is that possible?

Comment: yes still its possible., you need to get the checked ones separately using loop and then create the string you want

Comment: Ah, so the problem that how the string will be handle to get the final string, right?

Comment: yes , right now you are applying the logic on the way you handle checkboxes which is wrong

Comment: You can use ng-checked

Comment: @SaimaHaji Its not about ng-checked or unchecked its about how you handle data

Comment: @Sajeetharan he can do something like if user clicks check all, he can fire a function call on ng-change and can all the selected items in some array. along with this he will have to set the variable which will be used for ng-checked. To show checked boxes on UI. Later he can passed the maintain list in backend.

Comment: Hi @Sajeetharan, once again i got the problem with these checkboxes. It's too hard to check and ````concat```` string value on server, b'cause sometime the true value is not only one word like ````:banana:```` or ````:apple:````, it's also can be ````:banana::pieapple:```` for one checkbox. So i really stucked in here :(